# Django app deployed to Digitalocean 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python, django, nginx, digital-ocean

I have copyed my django app (that works locally) to a droplet from Digitalocean where I have installed the django 1-click app. 
I get 502 Bad Gateway and can't manage to understand why.

```
2018/03/13 22:25:06 [error] 2104#2104: *44 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 139.162.251.201, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/"
2018/03/13 22:28:19 [error] 2104#2104: *46 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.55.242.118, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "46.101.7.245"
2018/03/13 22:31:51 [error] 2104#2104: *49 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.55.242.118, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "46.101.7.245"
2018/03/13 22:32:05 [error] 2104#2104: *52 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 93.55.242.118, server: _, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/admin", host: "46.101.7.245"
2018/03/13 22:40:18 [error] 2104#2104: *55 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.55.242.118, server: _, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/admin", host: "46.101.7.245"
2018/03/13 22:40:23 [error] 2104#2104: *55 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.55.242.118, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "46.101.7.245"
2018/03/13 22:44:08 [error] 2104#2104: *59 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.55.242.118, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "46.101.7.245"
2018/03/13 22:44:08 [error] 2104#2104: *62 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.55.242.118, server: _, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/robots.txt", host: "46.101.7.245"
2018/03/13 22:56:30 [error] 2104#2104: *64 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 93.55.242.118, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "46.101.7.245"
2018/03/13 22:58:36 [error] 2104#2104: *67 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 93.55.242.118, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "46.101.7.245"
```

I am new to Django and to deployment to a server, and I can't understand the error. I have looked for answers but can't find a solution that works in my case. Is there a way to get more detailed errors? Thanks

Comment: DigitalOcean has great tutorials on deploying Django. Did you look at them? It looks like gunicorn is not serving it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In the logs you posted it says `upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/"` - that looks like your misconfigured your Nginx server and it can't connect to the Django app.

Make sure that the Nginx are set up to connect to either the socket (`unix:/...`) or the http endpoint that your Django app is serving traffic on.